# How to reset kafka streams application using the java code?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to remove all intermediate topics and reprocess data. On the development time I'm doing restart with this command;

```
docker exec -i containerName kafka-streams-application-reset.sh --bootstrap-servers :9092  --application-id  appid1
```

However, when working with more than one application, it causes unnecessary steps to be repeated. I want to do this before running the Java application? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`kafka-streams-application-reset.sh` is just a shell wrapper around a Scala class that you can import and call from code, sure

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/StreamsResetter.java

Comment: Thanks. Is it a common occurrence? What people do on the development-grade while develop a Kafka streams applications? Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You would only do reset while developing, not after the application is finalized unless the topology ends up in a bad state... and the suggestion has always been to just use the CLI command. There is a `cleanUp()` method, but that only empties the local filesystem, not internal topics.